# Get URL Params with '#'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a url that receive request with parameters set like this from the return URL of the GoogleAuth. :
LoginReturn.aspx#state=/profile&access_token=token&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

Because of '#' (instead of '?'), if I look in Request.QueryString or Request.RawUrl, there is no parameter and I need to get this access_token.

What is the correct way to get those parameters ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The #-Part is rarely transported to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that follows `#` is only for the browser. It's usually used to navigate to an anchor in a page, or for single page applications.

The correct way is to edit your query from `#` to `?`

Comment: How can I edit an url when a page is asked ?

Comment: ``string.replace('#', '?');``

Comment: Thanks but that was not what I meant ;) I manage to dot it in Javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace